# Maven tries download multimodule dependency on `validate` phase

Tags: java, maven, build

From a build pipeline I want to run `validate` phase for things like the `enforcer` plugin. However it does not work for a multimodule project as it tries to download dependencies from repository which are inside the project. However, `compile` phase does not do that, but for me it is not an option as it is too slow.

pom.xml:

```
<module>lib</module>
<module>app</module>
```

lib/pom.xml

```
 <version>1.2.3</version>
```

app/pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
   <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

So, if I do `mvn compile` it works fine.

But if I do `mvn validate` it fails validating `app` module as it tries to download lib-1.2.3 from maven repo. For some reason it now could not see that the lib is a neighbour dependency. Why?

I have created a small repo: https://github.com/kan-izh/so63963768

`mvn compile`

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-no-snapshots) @ app ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ app ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Workspace\repo\so63963768\app\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ app ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent ............................................ SUCCESS [1.612s]
[INFO] lib ............................................... SUCCESS [1.224s]
[INFO] app ............................................... SUCCESS [0.056s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

`mvn validate`

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-no-snapshots) @ app ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent ............................................ SUCCESS [0.979s]
[INFO] lib ............................................... SUCCESS [0.015s]
[INFO] app ............................................... FAILURE [0.020s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.180s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 23 11:27:38 BST 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/34M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-no-snapshots) on project app: Execution
 enforce-no-snapshots of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce failed: org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.
DependencyGraphBuilderException: Could not resolve following dependencies: [com.so.q63963768:lib:jar:1.2.3 (compile)]: Could not resolve depend
encies for project com.so.q63963768:app:jar:1.2.3: Failure to find com.so.q63963768:lib:jar:1.2.3 in http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
com:8081/repository/maven-public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has
 elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Do you run it on the main directory or from the subdirectory?

Comment: From main, where the parent pom is

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question, and it shows a small flaw in how Maven handles dependencies.
You need to know that for every plugin-goal you can define if dependencies should be resolved, and for which scope. (and there's a small difference if having only the poms is enough, or that you also need the artifacts)
[compiler:compile](https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/CompilerMojo.java#L61) requires the dependencies that are required during compile, [compiler:testCompile](https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/TestCompilerMojo.java#L58) requires the dependencies that are required during test.
For the enforce goal it is tricky: the goal itself doesn't require to have resolved dependencies, nor do most rules( like requireJavaVersion or requireMavenVersion), but some rules do, like the one you try to enforce.
Ideally rules can define if they need to have resolved dependencies, but right now the API doesn't support that.

So you have a couple of solutions: always run with compile, or have an execution-block bound to the compile-pahse if it requires artifacts.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the second solution. What do you mean by that?
And the third solution is to change the enforcer plugin to include `requiresDependencyResolution`? Why is it not done in the first place? Any downside?

Comment: <execution>
      <id>enforce-reactor</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

This will be executed after the `compiler:compile`, so that means that those dependencies will be available.

Always requiring dependencies doesn't make sense, as for most rules you don't need the dependencies, but you do want feedback as fast as possible.
The real solution is an improvement in Maven.

Comment: So, you are suggesting to move enforcer plugin to compile phase? What's the point? `mvn compile` works fine already.

Comment: you have some rules that depend on compile scoped dependencies. Easiest fix is to put only those rules in a separate execution block in the enforcer-plugin as shown in my previous answer. By doing that, `mvn validate` should work again.

Comment: Oh, no. That's just defeats the purpose. My initial goal was to build a pipeline which changes snapshot version to release version, validates that "no snapshot dependencies in release" and then commits/tags the change. I was hoping that I could do it fast, as validate works usually few seconds, while compile takes several minutes.

Comment: Ah, but that completely changes the original question, because it becomes condintional. I hope I clearly explained that the current design of Maven won't allow to dependency related enforcer rules with having these dependencies being resolved first. (and there are other solutions for your new release question)

Comment: What are other solutions?

Comment: Also it quite weird. The plugin in fact tries to resolve dependencies anyway, but somehow it is doing it wrongly so it fails with _Could not resolve following dependencies_. Why could it not do resolution properly?

Comment: Because those dependencies haven't been built yet.

Comment: I could not follow the explanation... Why maven needs to compile dependencies for validation? The `<dependencies>` structure is available and used by compile, however seems not in use by validate. At the moment I see the feature is just "not implemented" rather than it could not. Right?

Comment: The problem lies in https://github.com/apache/maven-enforcer/blob/master/maven-enforcer-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/enforcer/EnforceMojo.java#L53 which means: when calling this goal, I need all dependencies up to the test-scope. Maven recognizes lib as part of the multimodule, so it will use its `target/classes` or `jar`, but as long as these files haven't been "attached" (which is done by both comiler and jar plugin), Maven will fail saying it can't resolve the lib dependency.

Comment: Could it do similar to compiler plugin with `requiresDependencyResolution`? https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/CompilerMojo.java#L60
Compiler plugin obviously could not require compiled classes and works just fine.